Is there a way in InkScape, to reduce in one shot, several shapes in the same way as the gimp's reduce selection?
I have an SVG file of a tiling, which I need to import in OpenSCAD (a 3D modeling software):

However, since all the tiles are joined, OpenSCAD will see them as a whole and loose the frontiers between the tiles :

So, what I would need to do, is take the shape of all the tiles and reduce it the same way as in the selection reduction in the Gimp in order to make a regular gap between the tiles. as one can see, zooming out would not produce the right result.
However, as you could see, it would be quite tedious to do it by hand, tile by tile. So, is there a way to do that automatically with InkScape (or any other free vector oriented image processing software).

You can use 'Path → Inset' with all of your objects selected to quickly shrink them uniformly. By how much it shrinks them is determined by the 'Inset/Outset by' setting in the preferences under 'Behavior → Steps'.
Alternatively, to have a bit more control and do this non-destructively, you can group them all together (Ctrl+G), then add the 'Offset' path-effect to the group in the 'Path → Path Effects...' panel and set a negative offset.


Another solution is to use stroke to path. This may lead to more accurate results.

Select all shapes, open fill and stroke panel and remove fill,
choose the right stroke width (if you want a one millimeter gap
between each shape, set a one millimeter stroke width) and choose a
miter join (rightest icon of join options). Set a black stroke.
Then (all shapes are still selected) do path > stroke to path then path > union : this will create one unique complex black filled path.
From this path, do path > break apart. On canvas, you see a big black thing with dozens of shapes selected : all subpaths have been separated in individual paths.
You need to destroy the biggest path (the outer subpath of the path created in step 2), which should be normally on top of others. Use select tool, click somewhere else on canvas then click again on the bunch of shapes, you should see one big bounding box for the selected path. Alternatively, turn display mode to outline (view > display mode > outline) and use node tool to select the outermost path ("the perimeter"), switch to select tool and delete this path. That's all, you can switch to normal view.

